# How to access share drive path using credentials with Directory.Exists(path) in c#

Tags: c#

My task is to find share drive paths existence present in other servers and adding user to same path if exists.
To achieve this am using `Directory.Exists(path)` method and yes it is working only for paths which i have access.
But there are many restricted paths, so i have to use credentials (We have one service account and i want use that credentials through that we can access everything:  ) in order check for path existence.
Please provide me syntax or How to achieve the same, Please help me!!!

Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/125341/how-do-you-do-impersonation-in-net

Answer (score 0):

As @ColinM linked, you will need to impersonate that service account and then check if the directory exists with `Directory.Exists(path)`

http://michiel.vanotegem.nl/2006/07/windowsimpersonationcontext-made-easy/

The above article provides a nice wrapper class to do user impersonation.

https://www.codeproject.com/articles/4051/windows-impersonation-using-c

Also give this article a read as it provides a similiar example.